# How to print live data from DRF to reactjs?

Tags: python, reactjs

I want to display python live print values on react webpage, if its possible how can i do that ? for example:

```
data = ["1,2,3,4,5,6,7...n"]
print('data')  #<------   i want this live print values to be displayed on reactjs.
```

Comment: Are you using python in react?

Comment: Not python directly but with django and react. with axios is how both frameworks communicates. im using axios for communication.